# how to refresh a listview inside a FragmentPagerAdapter and in one fragment adds data and the list is displayed in the another fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragmentpageradapter

```
public class AllQuestions extends Fragment {

     ListView lstQuesions;
     QuestionsAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Question> questions;
     DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_questions_layout, container,false);
        lstQuesions = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lstQuestions);
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
        questions = dbHelper.getData();
        mAdapter = new QuestionsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lst_all_questions, questions);
        lstQuesions.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setDataToAdapter(){
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

here in `onResume()` the `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` shows `null` if I comment this line then it runs successfully and shows the list perfectly for the first time after launch.But when I add another input to database here the list was not refreshing.

I'm adding new item as

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnSave :
            if(resetFields()){
                String question = edtQuestion.getText().toString();
                String OptionA = edtOptionA.getText().toString();
                String OptionB = edtOptionB.getText().toString();
                String OptionC = edtOptionC.getText().toString();
                String OptionD = edtOptionD.getText().toString();
                Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date now = calender.getTime();
                Timestamp currentTimeStamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
                Question questionObj = new Question();
                questionObj.setUserquestion(question);
                questionObj.setOpta(OptionA);
                questionObj.setOptb(OptionB);
                questionObj.setOptc(OptionC);
                questionObj.setOptd(OptionD);
                questionObj.setCurrentDateTime(currentTimeStamp.toString());
                dbHelper.addData(questionObj);
            }
        break;
```

Comment: try to set *Adapter* in `onResume()` instead of `onCreateView(...)`

Comment: when I try to set adapter in onResume() like this@Override
 public void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
  mAdapter = new QuestionsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lst_all_questions, questions);
  lstQuesions.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }It was showing for the first time only but when I add a new item it doesn't refresh the list

Comment: how u add item in list

Comment: I have paste all the code in the above please try to help me

Comment: is ur save button present in same fragment or other fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllQuestions aq = (AllQuestions)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" +2);
                    aq.onResume();

Comment: After adding the code as shown in onResume()...It works fine..thank you Kaushik for help